# Multitenant Saas built in yii2

Tags: yii2, multi-tenant, saas

I am developing a multi-tenant LMS in yii2. All the tenants will have their respective user accounts. But to login to the system those user should also exists in main database, user table. So do I need to replicate the user accounts in both databases.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replicate the users table  You could simply create a common table for user  .. and manager the access  to the common db redifining the tableName()  function  ..

```
  class MyUserClass  extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
  {
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */
      public static function tableName()
      {

          return 'common_database.' 'user_table';
      }
```

....

```
  class MyTenancyModel  extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
  {
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */
      public static function tableName()
      {

          return  'my_tenancy_table';
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understood the concept that you're talking about. But what is the use of MyTenanceModel here?

Comment: for MyTenancyModel    i mean each model that is managed  in the multi tenancy env ..  alias  each table/model  that your multitenancy application use

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will surely try this.